# MySQL is 100% CPU over the past week, no idea why, details below

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sql-server, sql

I'm trying to work out why MySQL is hitting 100% over the past week:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/NQH5dR0.png]

It's a server that does network/server monitoring called LibreNMS.

Top:
https://pastebin.com/1qypfm0n

Here I access MySQL and look at the processes:
https://pastebin.com/zCVMh2cL

and full processes
https://pastebin.com/0ZFhqpiF

I then found a tool called MySQLTuner, but I'm not experienced enough to understand the results:
https://pastebin.com/yBQzCuQU

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Remove [sql-server] unless it is somehow significant.  You have 24GB of RAM?

Answer (score 0):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
```

will probably help a lot.  It is currently set to an old default that is much too small.  So it seems to be doing a lot of I/O.  And toward the end of the graph, it shows an overwhelming amount of I/O.  (The PROCESSLIST shows essentially nothing running, perhaps it was after you restarted?)

You should also turn on the slowlog to help identify what queryies are "worst".  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog